# What are the ideals of $F_2[x]/\langle x^2 + x +1\rangle$?

Tags: field-theory, ideals

Is it just the divisors of $x^2 +x+1$ in mod $2$ ?

Comment: You should use \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ instead of < and > in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;x^2+x+1\in\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ is irreducible, the ideal $\;I:=\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle\;$ is prime and thus maximal, so $\;\Bbb F_2[x]/I\;$ is a field, and its ideals are...

Comment: Haha. I like how similar our answers are.

Comment: @Jake Indeed so...and so is Jack's answer. I think it is because this is standard material.

Comment: Would it be $0,1,x,x+1$ ?

Comment: @Conor No, those are *the elements* of the field, assuming you mean in fact $\;x=X+I\;,\,\,X\in\Bbb F_2[X]\;$ , with the relation $\;x^2=x+1\;$ . What are the **only** ideals in *any* field?

Comment: @Joanpemo Okay, so the ring can only be a field iff the only ideals are 0 and 1.

Comment: @Conor Exactly that! The *commutative unitary ring*, that is. And the ideal $\;1\;$ is in fact the whole ring.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$, since it has no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

It follows that $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is a finite field with four elements.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal you are taking the quotient by is prime (and thus maximal, since $F_2[x]$ is a PID). So the quotient is a field. So it's ideals are..what?